# how can git commit -a work after i remove a file from index

Tags: git, github, git-commit, rm, git-rm

Suppose I have tracked file `empty.txt`.
Now I remove file from working directory using `rm empty.txt` .
Now I am removing file from index using `git rm empty.txt` and now file should be untracked since I have removed it from index.
After this I used `git commit -a -m "remove empty.txt"` but how it is working as -a parameter is used to skip explicitly adding tracked file to staging area but I already removed file from index?
It should be untracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible misconceptions:

- This has nothing to do with "tracking".
- A git commit is not about *changes*. It is a snapshot, a photograph, of your entire set of files, as reflected in the index, which is itself a complete copy of your entire set of files.

If you take a photograph of a dog standing among two trees, the photograph contains a dog and two trees. That is a commit.

If the dog walks away and you take another photograph, the photograph contains the two trees but *not* the dog. It wasn't there when you took that photograph. That is another commit.

There is no "removal" action involved in the creation of the second commit. It isn't a modification of the first photograph. It's just a photograph of what is.

In the case of a git commit that you create, "what is" is the index, plain and simple (by default; there are ways around this, by saying `git commit someFile`, but ignore that for our purposes).

---

Okay, so, on to the details of your question. You say:

> i remove file from working directory using `rm empty.txt`
>
> now i am removing file from index using `git rm empty.txt`
>
> after this i used `git commit -a`

So:

- If you remove a file from the working tree, `git commit -a` automatically removes that file from the index as well (as if by calling `git rm --cached`) before making the commit. The file is now not in the index and therefore the commit created from it is missing that file (just like the dog).
- In your case, you *yourself* removed the file from *both* the working tree *and* the index. So now the `-a` part of `git commit -a` has no work to do with regard to the index as far as this file is concerned; you already did that work. And now very same operation occurs: the file is now not in the index and therefore the commit created from it is missing that file (just like the dog).

Comment: This is 100% wrong, so it's a bit odd that it's upvoted and accepted.  The `-a` commit option *absolutely* has to do with files being untracked, and the commit process is *sbsolutely* about recognizing the differences between the previous snapshot and the new one being created.

Answer (score -2):

Initially I thought the docs were pretty clear about this, but after testing there is a bit of a weird case here...

So for the most part, the `-a` flag is going to *skip* the index and apply the changes from your worktree.  Deleting a file is a change.  My reading of the (perhaps ambiguous) docs would suggest that the index would be basically ignored, *except* that new files wouldn't be added.

There's some weirdness in the case where a file in the previous commit is removed from the stage, though.  What my tests show is, in this case *the file is removed from the new commit* based on being removed from the index; and then any further changes in the work tree (i.e. if the file was recreated) are ignored.  In that sense, what OP observed is consistent - it's just hard to get that out of a reading of the docs.

It is too bad, because it ruins a bunch of seemingly-true simple statements that would describe the behavior; but here it is:

```
git init
touch file1
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"

echo CHANGES > file1
git rm --cached file1
git status

# this will show a staged change to remove the file, and an untracked file
# with the CHANGES

git commit -a -mtest
```

...and now the commit has an empty directory, and `file1` is untracked.  And with that in mind, the case in the question is just the degenerate case where the change in the worktree is the same as the change in the index.